# embedding vector search efficient algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, search, data-structures, similarity

**background:** I have a machine learning model in which given an object returns an embedding vector with dimension d, the model is trained in a way such that the semantic similarity of two embedding vectors is very close. Now, the verification process is relatively simple, I can take something like the cosine similarity of the two vectors. For recognition, it's a little bit complicated, either I can loop through all the anchor documents and compare the cosine similarity, or use something like kNN (online).

**problem:** I have a list of embedding vectors, each vector has a dimension d, with length N. Each vector contains floating-point data.

What will be an efficient data structure + algorithm that can do the following:

1. Can add a new vector with a unique ID to the list efficiently (<= logarithmic complexity)
2. Search with a random vector in the list, and retrieve top k vectors, such that the Manhattan distance / L1 norm is minimum for those vectors efficiently (hopefully, <= logarithmic complexity).

**example:**

```
[
 [1., 2., 3.],
 [5., 6., 8.],
 [-11., 2., 31.]
]
```

`k = 2`
`query = [1.5, 2.5, 3.2]`
`results:`

```
[
 [1., 2., 3.],
 [5., 6., 8.],
]
```

Comment: I'd look into [approximate nearest neighbor algorithms](https://towardsdatascience.com/comprehensive-guide-to-approximate-nearest-neighbors-algorithms-8b94f057d6b6). Depending on the data (particularly whether or not `N >> d`), some form of locality sensitive hashing or kd-tree based approach would seem appropriate.

Comment: Thanks, that's definitely helpful, I have found some good resources here: https://www.infoworld.com/article/3634357/what-is-vector-search-better-search-through-ai.html

Comment: I wrote a [few articles](https://www.pinecone.io/learn/) you might find useful on ANN algorithms, you have various approaches like [IVF](https://www.pinecone.io/learn/vector-indexes/) or [HNSW](https://www.pinecone.io/learn/hnsw/), and can [mix and match several combinations](https://www.pinecone.io/learn/composite-indexes/) of these too. The answer to your question depends on the size of your dataset more than anything else, anything particularly large 1M+ is IVF+HNSW territory

Comment: thanks, @JamesBriggs. I will look into it.

Comment: Yes, the number of vectors will reach 1M+.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Faiss is exactly what you are looking for. The Github page is [here](https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss), if you are interested in the implementation details (this is pretty technical) see [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.08734), and the tutorial is [here](https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss/wiki/Getting-started).

Answer (score 0):

With inclusion of neural networks in many different software products, this problem has become very common and hence there are many algorithms available for this.

To select the right tool for your problem will be based on tradeoff between

- `speed`: how fast you want the algo/library to be?
- `recall`: how often the retrieved embedding is the optimal neighbor.

This tradeoff for different packages is nicely present in http://ann-benchmarks.com/ which benchmarks many different approximate nearest neighbor algorithms search packages. This would be a good place to start.

For long time maintainability perspective you also want to consider community (eg. git repo stars, latest push, PR), code quality etc.